# Using gulp-git how to use git-dir and work-tree when

Tags: git, gulp

I am trying to fire a git command using gulp-git, but I am having trouble because I have extra arguments that need to be included in my git command. Namely git-dir and work-tree. The git command is as follows:

```
git --git-dir=../git_repos/dev --work-tree=../dev status
```

When I run this from the command line in the same folder as my gulpfile.js it works correctly, but I can't figure out the correct way to include the extra arguments.

My basic test gulp task looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var git = require('gulp-git');    

gulp.task('gitDevStatus', function(){
    git.status({ cwd: "--git-dir=../git_repos/dev --work-tree=../dev" }, function (err, stdout) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(stdout));
        console.log("DONE");
    });
});
```

The line I am having trouble with is:

```
git.status({ cwd: "--git-dir=../git_repos/dev --work-tree=../dev" }, ...
```

If I run it without any arguments I of course if fails because it can't find git files:

```
git.status({ }, ... 
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

if I put the extra variables as args I get:

```
git.status({ args: "--git-dir=../git_repos/dev --work-tree=../dev" },
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Which would suggest that the args in this case are not changing the executed git command

Finally if I add them in cwd: as in my full task example I get:

```
 git.status({ cwd: "--git-dir=../git_repos/dev --work-tree=../dev" }, ...
 Error: spawn ENOENT
```

This error I understand to be because it is unable to find a file or directory, but at least it is no longer complaining that there is no .git

Other things I have tried include wrapping the directory definitions in nested quotes:

```
 git.status({ cwd: "--git-dir='../git_repos/dev' --work-tree='../dev'" }, ...
```

All attempts end with the same **spawn ENOENT** error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should be dealing with this type of more complex git command in gulp-git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some rest and another look at the gulp-git documentation I tried using the exec function and got a successful result:

```
git.exec({args : '--git-dir=../git_repos/dev --work-tree=../dev status'}, function (err, stdout) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

I am not sure if this is best practice, so I would appreciate further input if anyone has more knowledge to share.